# Free vpn software for windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn

I need a free vpn software. In my country, I can’t reach almost all HTTPS website. I try to use opera developer browser the closed site works.

Can i find any software do this job to use chrome

Comment: Try using the Tor Browser and associated tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All VPN clients are either free or come as a trial. You need to **pay for the service**, not the client. If you are desperate, there are the following items you could use:

1. [TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/b/privacy/?aff_id=1080&offer_id=27&trans_id=102058e9dc5d8eb3ea136ecb3e31a5&utm_campaign=bestvpn-free&utm_source=Affiliate&utm_medium=BestVPN)- free 500 MB of usage per month, else $8.00 per month unlimited data;
2. [Windscribe](https://windscribe.com/upgrade) - Free 2 GB of data with 1 active connection across 9 locations;
3. [CyberGhost](https://www.cyberghostvpn.com/en_us#/buy)
4. [ZoogTV](https://zoogtv.com/pricing) - 2 GB data with 3 VPN servers, running 1 active connection;

You can try [CyberGhost free Web Proxy for browsing](https://www.cyberghostvpn.com/en_us/free-proxy) if you'd prefer; it may suit your needs better than an actual VPN, or even [VPN Gate](https://www.vpngate.net/en/).

Lastly, I would recommend you use the [Tor network](https://www.torproject.org/) for browsing.

Comment: Think you I try Tunnel Bear it's awesome